# "Invalid query" exception without clear reason

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

What is wrong with next WMi query? (i got "Invalid query" managment exception).

```
        const string deviceName = "04157DF42C9B1109";

        string wmiQuery = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_USBControllerDevice WHERE Antecedent LIKE '%{0}%'", deviceName);

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
        ManagementObjectCollection retObjectCollection = searcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject retObject in retObjectCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}]:{1}", retObject["Antecedent"], retObject["Dependent"]);
        }
```

Comment: do you have a DB connection? try running the query simply (without LIKE) or even hardcode the LIKE parameter just for testing

Comment: @NikosM. query syntasys is valid.. you can try o nyour env. with hardcoded like works

Comment: The query doesn't work because the `Antecedent` property is a Reference to a CIM object, and the `LIKE ` operator only can be used in `string` type properties.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out how to fix the original error but the following approach may be used as a workaround:

```
string wmiQuery = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_USBControllerDevice");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
ManagementObjectCollection retObjectCollection = searcher.Get();

var retObjectList = retObjectCollection.Cast<ManagementObject>()
    .Where(m => ((string)m["Antecedent"]).Contains(deviceName))
    .ToList();

foreach (ManagementObject retObject in retObjectList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]:{1}", retObject["Antecedent"], retObject["Dependent"]);
}
```

I noticed other people having the same issue and some people suggested using **ASSOCIATORS OF** statement (Resource: https://superuser.com/questions/740564/wmi-query-based-on-antecedent-string) That's the accepted answer here so it might just work for you too.

Comment: same workaround I am using now, but still qurous why like not working.. this wastes time

Answer (score 0):

id suggest you use pure string instead of formatting it: 
This:

```
 string wmiQuery = "select * from Win32_USBControllerDevice where Antecedent like '%" + deviceName + "%'";
```

instead of this:

```
 string wmiQuery = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_USBControllerDevice WHERE Antecedent LIKE '%{0}%'", deviceName);
```

And one more thing: Why do you need to use const on the string? Maybe that could be your problem also.

Comment: Whether he uses `String.Format` or not won't change anything.. and `String.Format` generally looks neater..

Comment: I am unable to debug his code so it was just an idea from me.